# Using bash variables with docker run non-interactively

Tags: bash, docker

I would like to reference an environment variable non-interactively when using `docker run` in the following manner:

```bash
docker run my-image:v3.8-dev echo "$MY_PACKAGE_VERSION"
```

The problem is that of course when I run this command on *bare metal* in my local shell, the variable substitution happens *before* the `docker run` and so the environment variable `MY_PACKAGE_VERSION` which is unset in my environment is substituted in and I just see the Docker container run and print a blank line, i.e. the echo with an empty string passed to it.

How can I ensure that the "$MY_PACKAGE_VERSION" argument to the [command I am passing / overriding](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options) is interpreted *inside* the Docker environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quote it once more so it doesn't get interpreted by your current shell:

```
docker run my-image:v3.8-dev bash -c 'echo "$MY_PACKAGE_VERSION"'
```